# How to Update NSLayoutConstraint in StoryBoard?

Tags: ios, swift, nslayoutconstraint

I created 2 Button in my superView , Now I want change the `@IBOutlet weak var bottomLayOut: NSLayoutConstraint!` depend on the user role .

the example is: if the user is a agent role but not a teacher role  I want update the `NSLayoutConstraint` 's second item from Teacher Entry .bottom to AgentEntry button's bottom .

[image]
is that posible?

Update :

solve this by turn `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` to true:
e.g : `teacherBtn.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true`
than, we can use both constraints and code to change teacherBtn's frame

Comment: just wondering, why not you change the button name and color based on the role instead of changing constraints?

Comment: the 2 button can be show on same time

Comment: let me understand a bit clearly.. let's say the user role is teacher, so you want to show the teacher button on top and agent button on bottom, isn't it?

Comment: there are 3 patterns : both teacher and agent role - show both 2 button, only teacher role - show teacher button , only agent role - show agent button.

Comment: ok not sure how you wanna do it but i can suggest using `setFrame:CGRectMake` . this one you can use for positioning the buttons and to hide buttons you can use `button.hidden = YES;` .  I would recommend you not to mess up with constraint

Comment: but once you used Autolayout, you can't use code to change the frame , right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153081/discussion-between-neko-and-mohammad-julfikar).

Comment: Use autolayout programatically. case 1- If both teacher and agent role - dont hidden any button. case 2 - only teacher role - agent button make it hidden and make bottom constraint of teacher button isactive false. And give top constraint for that button(programatically). 3 - only agent role - Just hidden the teacher button.

Answer (score 2):

Two ways I can think of to do this off the top of my head:

1. Set up the constraints programmatically. Create a property containing the current constraints on the buttons, and then you can do something along the lines of (disclaimer: written in Chrome, may contain typos, edit as appropriate):

`    if let constraints = self.buttonConstraints {
        NSLayoutConstraint.deactivate(constraints)
    }

```
let views: [String : UIView] = ["Agent" : self.agentButton, "Teacher" : self.teacherButton]

let newConstraints: [NSLayoutConstraint] = {
    switch role {
    case .teacherAndAgent:
        self.teacherButton.isHidden = false
        self.agentButton.isHidden = false
        return NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:[agent]-[teacher]-|", metrics: nil, views: views)
    case .teacherOnly:
        // you get the idea
    case .agentOnly:
        // ditto
    }
}()

NSLayoutConstraint.activate(newConstraints)
self.buttonConstraints = newConstraints`
```

2. What might be simpler, though, is to use a UIStackView to hold your buttons. On current macOS at least, NSStackView automatically adjusts the layout based on which of its views are hidden; if UIStackView on iOS behaves the same way, it may do a lot of the work for you without having to manually fuss with layout constraints.